# SetExpressCheckout variable issue in Paypal sendbox

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, express-checkout

[image]I want to  implement SetExpressCheckout in my application 
i have some variable issue how to set first name , last name and email address

I follow the link

https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECCustomizing

where i did not able to set email address on Paypal Sendbox

&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_EMAIL=jsmith01@example.com

I am attaching issue actually 
How to set Last Name and email

[image]

Please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Express Checkout includes the ability to provide multiple payments in a single flow (parallel payments) so that's why the parameters include that 0,1,2, etc. in the middle.  What you're showing here is correct, so I'm not exactly sure what your question is..??  Are you getting some sort of error or are you just not seeing an email address in the payment details, or what?

If you're working with PHP I'd recommend taking a look at my [PHP Class Library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/).  It will make the Express Checkout integration very simple for you.

Comment: Hi Andrew ,Thanks for your response but i am working in .NET, i am not able to set email address on paypal sendbox  -- Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.  What you've shown in your question is you setting the email.  Are you saying it's not showing up in the transaction details after the payment is made?

Comment: HI Andrew , now i have attach screen short , In this line &PAYMENTREQUEST_0_EMAIL=jsmith01@example.com  set the value of email address , my case i am not able to set email address on Paypal sendbox , I think now you got my question what i am asking .  Thanks